# ExoPlayer with Equalizer - sound too loud at start

Tags: android, exoplayer, equalizer

I have an Android app, where music is being played using the [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer). I've added [Equalizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer) functionality, but it seems that on some devices (Pixel 6, Huawei P40) there is an issue, when Equalizer is being enabled. When ExoPlayer is initialized and `equalizer.setEnabled(true)` is called, there is a very loud sound for a few miliseconds. Although it is very short, it seems that it is caused by increasing the volume of the particular stream significantly, until it's back to normal. When I tried to delay `setEnabled(true)` call for a few seconds, the issue was resolved, but this doesn't feel like correct approach.

Has anybody of you encountered this issue and solved it? I tried to enable the equalizer in different places (when instantiating the ExoPlayer instance, in `onPlaybackStateChanged` method, etc.), but the issue was always there.

Code:

```
exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
equalizer = new Equalizer(0, exoPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
equalizer.setEnabled(true);
// Bands and presets are set here
// ...
// exoplayer is prepared, listeners are added, etc.
```

I'm sure the issue is caused by Equalizer, because if the equalizer-related code is not called, or if `equalizer.setEnabled()` is called with `false`, everything is OK.

Comment: Have you encountered this using Media3?